# Git searching questions

Tags: git

I am able to use the commands no problem and I've done some poking about with them to try and figure this out but I can't figure out exactly how/where the searching is being done.

The commands I'm using are

```
git grep "pattern"
git log -S <string> 
git log -G "pattern"
git log -L :pattern:file
```

So I can add patterns I want to search for but I am not exactly sure why the results that are returned to me are.

In other words, I've read the man pages, I know how to use the tools but don't really know what they are doing.
I know this is a pretty soft question but if someone could provide some insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: perhaps see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It really isn't clear what you're trying to ask right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to clear it out as much as I can for you:

---

#### `git grep "pattern"`

This pattern will search for content in **files**

[image]

---

#### `git log -S <word>`

The `pickaxe search` (`git log -S`) search for the **added or removed**  in the content of the commit, meaning searching for the commit which added or removed this content and not in a **commit message** but rather in the content and the output is the commit which **introduced** this change.

[image]

---

#### `git log -G "pattern"`

Display the changes made on the `reflog`. The `reflog` record changes made to the `HEAD` and this option is "walking" on the reflog and print out the changes made on it. `reflog` record changes even when no actual file was updated or changes, simply the `HEAD` changes and the `-G` print out all the records which introduced changes.

[image]

---

#### `git log -L`

This pattern is a simple one. Its simply print out which commit changed the given line range of the given file

### [image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I know the question wasn't great but I was finding the documentation a bit opaque on this one.

Answer (score 0):

[git grep](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#_description) searches in files, line by line, and display found lines.

[git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_description) lists commits. Options allow to limit what commits it lists and how it displays them.